# XML document separated by line breaks

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
I need to be able to output the text of an XML document separated by line breaks
```

please check in what problem my code
    xml:-

<ShortNote>
<CatchWord><HiddenData>Criminal Law — </HiddenData>Police</CatchWord>     — <CatchWord><HiddenData>Appointment to Sensitive Posts —     </HiddenData>Director General of Police (DGP)</CatchWord>
</ShortNote>

```
Need output following
<ShortNote>
<SNHeading1>Criminal Law</SNHeading1>
<SNHeading2>Police</SNHeading2>
<SNHeading3>#Appointment to Sensitive Posts</SNHeading3>
<SNHeading4>Director General of Police (DGP)</SNHeading4>
</ShortNote>

following code use but not output according to me:-
<xsl:template match="ShortNote/CatchWord">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            <xsl:if test="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text,'&#8212;'),'&#8212;'))!=''">
    <xsl:element name="SNHeading{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text,'&#8212;'),'&#8212;'))"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text,'&#8212;')">
        <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:message>
        <xsl:element name="SNHeading{position()+1}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&#8212;')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming at least XSLT 2.0 I think you can simply process `CatchWord/tokenize(., '—')` e.g. in XSLT 3

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="ShortNote">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="CatchWord!tokenize(., '—')!normalize-space()"/> 
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]" expand-text="yes">
      <xsl:element name="SNHeading{position()}">{.}</xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9u

For XSLT 2 where you can't match on a string you can use `xsl:for-each`:

```
  <xsl:template match="ShortNote">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each select="for $s in CatchWord/tokenize(., '—') return normalize-space($s)">
            <xsl:element name="SNHeading{position()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9u/1

Comment: one more query:-
how to increase empty tag <SNHeading> more than 12

Comment: @AjeetSingh, I don't understand what you are asking, it might better to ask a new question with the necessary details of input, XSLT, result you get and the one you want.

Comment: Ask a new question if you can't figure it out on your own, using the `to` operator in XSLT/XPath 2 you can easily create sequences as needed.

Comment: my new requirement
<ShortNote>
<SNHeading1>Criminal Law</SNHeading1>
<SNHeading2>Police</SNHeading2>
<SNHeading3>#Appointment to Sensitive Posts</SNHeading3>
<SNHeading4>Director General of Police (DGP)</SNHeading4>

<SNHeading5/>

<SNHeading6/>

<SNHeading7/>

<SNHeading8/>

<SNHeading9/>

<SNHeading10/>

<SNHeading11/>

<SNHeading12>
</ShortNote>

Comment: please explain in depth

Comment: See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9u/2 for an XSLT 3 or https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9u/3 for an XSLT 2 suggestion to add missing empty elements using an XPath `to` expression.